# Rails 4: Any Recommendation on optimizing this app? Rendering: posts/index and others

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, optimization

I installed gem 'rack-mini-profiler' for this rails 4 app and it came up with issues. How do I go an optimize listings below? I'm not sure how to solve it, any help would greatly be appreciated, I've attached photos.

PostsController.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote, :downvote]
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]


    def index
 @users = User.all

        if 
            params[:category].blank?
            @posts = Post.all.order(:cached_votes_score => :desc).paginate(page:params[:page], per_page: 8 )

        else
            @category_id = Category.all 
            @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
            @posts = Post.where(category_id: @category_id).order(:cached_votes_up => :desc).paginate(page:params[:page], per_page: 8 )

        end

        if  @user = current_user

            @post = current_user.posts.build
            @purchased = Sale.where(buyer_email: current_user.email).order("created_at DESC").order("created_at DESC").paginate(page:params[:page], per_page: 1 )
      @sales = Sale.where(seller_email: current_user.email).order("created_at DESC").order("created_at DESC").paginate(page:params[:page], per_page: 1 )
        else
        end

    end

private

    def find_post
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        if  @user = current_user
        @purchased = Sale.where(buyer_email: current_user.email).order("created_at DESC").order("created_at DESC").paginate(page:params[:page], per_page: 1 )
      @sales = Sale.where(seller_email: current_user.email).order("created_at DESC").order("created_at DESC").paginate(page:params[:page], per_page: 1 )
        end
    end

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :link, :description, :category_id, :banner, :user_id)
    end

end
```

This is the index.html

```
          <%= link_to "All", root_url, id:"category-color" %>
          <% Category.all.each do |category| %>

          <%= link_to category.name, posts_path(category: category.name), id:"category-color" %> 
        <% end %>



<% @posts.each do |post| %> 


      <% unless post.user.blank? %>
        <%=link_to image_tag(post.user.avatar.url(:thumb)), post.user %> <%= link_to post.user.name.capitalize, post.user %>  - <%= 'Published ' + time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) + ' ago' %> 


            <% if signed_in? %>


             <% if @current_user.pending_friends.include?(post.user) %>  
             Pending Friend Request
             <% else %>
             <% end %>   


           <% if @current_user.friends.include?(post.user)%>  
           Friend
           <% else %>
           <% end %>


           <% if post.user.pending_friends.include?(@current_user) %>
           Friend Request
           <% else %>
           <% end %>

         <% end %>      

       <% end %>      


            <% if post.user.subscribed == true %>  

               <%= link_to "Store", post.user %>

               <%= link_to post.title, post  %>

            <%= post.get_likes.size %>
                Likes

            <%= post.get_dislikes.size %>
                Dislikes

            <%= post.comments.size %>
                Comments


                <% else %>  

            <%= post.title  %><


            <%= post.get_likes.size %>
                Likes

            <%= post.get_dislikes.size %>
                Dislikes

            <%= post.comments.size %>
                Comments

                    <% end %> 


     <%= truncate( raw( sanitize(post.description, :tags => %w(table tr td), :attributes => %w(id class style) ) ), :length => 320, :omission => " ... ") %>                             


<%= link_to "Read", post_path(post) %>

    <% end %>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Be more specific on what the issues are exactly

Comment: @Snappawapa, I'm not that advanced with rails. Main issue is optimizing rails for Memory usage. I've noticed in heroku I am getting  Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) and after researching was told to optimize the application. For example, how do I optimize `SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"` that rack-mini-profiler told me is taking `T+114.1 ms`

Comment: This is a more appropriate question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As a note `if @user = current_user` will always be true unless `current_user` is `nil` or `false` becuase you are just assigning (`=`) `current_user` to the instance variable `@user` rather than making a logical comparison which would be `==`.

Comment: Yeah, especially since you don't seem to be using nor defining the `@user` anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of issues, here are a couple just in the index controller:

```
@category_id = Category.all 
@category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
```

The first "Category.all" is a big unnecessary request since you replace "@category_id"'s value right after.

```
@purchased = Sale.where(buyer_email: current_user.email).order("created_at DESC").order("created_at DESC").paginate(page:params[:page], per_page: 1 )
@sales = Sale.where(seller_email: current_user.email).order("created_at DESC").order("created_at DESC").paginate(page:params[:page], per_page: 1 )
```

Here you perform twice the "order" on your query, this is also completely unnecessary.

Finally it doesn't seem to me like you are making any use of the

```
@users = User.all
```

anywhere in the code, so you can probably just get rid of it.